# Quitar o no generar atributo xmlns

Tags: vb6

Acabo de instalarme windows 10. Antes tenía W7. Mi proyecto en Visual Basic 6 me obliga a declarar las variables msxml2.DOMDocument como msxml2.DOMDocument60. Entiendo que estoy usando la msxml6.dll. El caso es que ahora el mismo código que antes me generaba algo así:

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http:?//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
<GrpHdr>
```

...
ahora me genera esto con un atributo adicional xmlns="" que me da problemas:

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http:?//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CstmrDrctDbtInitn xmlns="">
<GrpHdr>
```

¿Sabéis como evitarlo?
He probado a hacer esto:

```
xmlCstmrDrcDbtInitn.removeAttribute ("xmlns")
```

pero no funciona.

Gracias

Comment: Echa un vistazo [aqui](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1722071) a ver si resuelve tu problema

Answer (score 0):

En ese enlace encontré la guía para ver donde fallaba.

El problema es que usaba createelement en lugar de createnode. De esa forma ya no se genera ese atributo no deseado. El tema queda así:

Antes ponía por ejemplo:

```
 Set xmlNbOfTxs = xmlRemesa.createElement("NbOfTxs")
 xmlGrpHdr.appendChild xmlNbOfTxs
```

y lo correcto es hacer esto:

```
Set xmlNbOfTxs = xmlRemesa.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "NbOfTxs", sNameSpaceURI)
```

donde en sNameSpaceURI tenemos esto:

```
Const sNameSpaceURI As String = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"
```

Cambiando los createelement por createnode de esa forma me ha ido perfecto.